# Data for last day a reminder letter was sent to customer

Tags: sql, db2

I have encountered a problem with my query. My objective is to get the customers, who have received reminder letters in past 14 days (rolling) and only get the last (max) date they have received it. Below is the query and the results. I could only post the picture as a link. 
[Results for the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13eSV.png)

```
select ar.AHCMP, ar.AHCUS#, cm.CMNAME, max(ar.AHDLTR)
from WSDATARG.ARIHDRFL ar
left join WSDATARG.CUSMASFL cm on CMCMP=AHCMP and CMCUS#=AHCUS#
where AHCMP in ('14','15','20')
and AHDLTR != '0'
--and AHDLTR between current_date-14 and current_date
group by ar.AHCMP, ar.AHCUS#, cm.CMNAME, ar.AHDLTR
```

As you can see from the result I get multiple lines for the same customer with different dates. And the AHDLTR (date reminder letter sent) doesn't want to work with current date expression. The field type from the table in Zoned Decimal, I tried "translating" that to date, but couldn't succeed. 
[Table properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzlzP.png)

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: What database are you using?  Is it really DB2?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it is IBM DB2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will build upon Gordon Linoff's answer. Conversion of your pseudo-date fields could look like this in db2 (I have now no possibility to test it):

```
select ar.AHCMP, ar.AHCUS#, cm.CMNAME, 
    DATE(TIMESTAMP(max(ar.AHDLTR) || '000000'))
from WSDATARG.ARIHDRFL ar left join
     WSDATARG.CUSMASFL cm
     on cm.CMCMP = ar.AHCMP and
        cm.CMCUS# = ar.AHCUS#
where ar.AHCMP in ('14', '15', '20') and
      ar.AHDLTR <> '0' and
      ar.AHDLTR >= REPLACE(CHAR(CURRENT DATE - 14 DAYS), '-', '')
group by ar.AHCMP, ar.AHCUS#, cm.CMNAME;
```

I am casting AHDLTR (e.g. '20180903') followed by 6 zeroes (hours, minutes, seconds - to get one of the standard timestamp formats, e.g. '20180903000000') to TIMESTAMP, then to DATE (as I think you wanted to), to get the date  2018-09-03.

When searching, I have to convert date (current -14, e.g. 2018-08-25) to CHAR (e.g. '2018-08-25') and remove hyphens (replace with empty string to e.g. 20180825).

Comment: You might find that `CHAR(INTEGER(CURRENT DATE - 14 DAYS))` would also get you to `20180825`

Comment: @Pavol Adam, your query helped me out with the pseudo-date fields. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have one too many expressions in the `GROUP BY`.  Try this:

```
select ar.AHCMP, ar.AHCUS#, cm.CMNAME, max(ar.AHDLTR)
from WSDATARG.ARIHDRFL ar left join
     WSDATARG.CUSMASFL cm
     on cm.CMCMP = ar.AHCMP and
        cm.CMCUS# = ar.AHCUS#
where ar.AHCMP in ('14', '15', '20') and
      ar.AHDLTR <> '0' and
      ar.AHDLTR >= current_date - 14
group by ar.AHCMP, ar.AHCUS#, cm.CMNAME;
```

You should only be aggregating by the *unaggregated* columns in the `select`.

Comment: Hey Gordon, 
I think that would work indeed, but the main issue is that the AHDLTR is a text field with date in form on YYYYMMDD. If I could translate it somehow to DATE format with the same format as YYYYMMDD would be the solution, then current_date should work as well.
 Also mentioned that in the original post, that I tried to translate, but couldn't get it in DATE format.

Comment: @JaanisVeinberg . . . Does casting it to a date work?  Otherwise, use `to_date()`.

Comment: I didn't get cast to work and somehow seem to not get to_date() working, could you perhaps help me out. Still learning SQL as a tool. :)